# 3d Preview software

Tags: blender, 3d

Is there any 3d preview type software? Basically I have a large number of 3d model meshes. Top import/open each one to try find something in particular is very tedious. So i was hoping there is something that opens a preview of the mesh? I have heard windows does it and I have this image as an example. Was hoping Linux has something similar. so far all I have seen is apps that can open them, not actually show a small preview of it. BTW most of mine are in FBX formwat.

https://polycount.com/discussion/191538/fbx-previews-in-windows-10-by-far-the-coolest-feature

Answer (score 0):

Assuming STL files...

```
$ fstl

Command 'fstl' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install fstl

$ gmsh

Command 'gmsh' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install gmsh
```

Googling: https://all3dp.com/1/free-stl-viewer-mac-online-stl-file-viewer/
Which is mostly Windowish though.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to get this resolved myself. I installed f3d through ubuntu's regular repo's and that allowed me to get actual thumbnails in the regular filemanager.